# R Function that will accept multiple group_by and summarise arguments

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a tibble that contains details of work activity done on various projects. I am trying to write a generic function that can run a fairly simple query on the tibble using `dplyr` verbs, of the form:

```
df %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  summarise(total_time = sum(duration))
```

This is straightforward enough to do with just a single grouping variable and summary variable. My problem comes when I try to generalise the function to accept multiple grouping and/or summary variables. I've attempted to do this using three functions, which are below (so there's quite a bit of code here).

```
proj_activity_report <- function(query_id) {

    projects <- read_rds('~/work_tracker/projects.rds')
    users <- read_rds('~/work_tracker/users.rds')
    activity <- read_rds('~/work_tracker/activity.rds')

    activity %>% 
        filter(project_id %in% query_id) %>% 
        left_join(projects, by = 'project_id') %>% 
        left_join(users, by = c('user_id.x' = 'user_id')) %>% 
        mutate(full_name = paste(forename, surname),
               start_date = format(date(time_started), '%d %b %Y'),
               logged_date = format(date(time_logged), '%d %b %Y')) %>% 
        arrange(project_id, time_started) %>% 
        select(Activity_ID = activity_id,
               Project_ID = project_id,
               Activity_Type = activity_title,
               Project_Title = project_title,
               Worker_Name = full_name,
               Date_Started = start_date,
               Duration_mins = duration,
               Date_Logged = logged_date,
               Comments = comments,
               Project_Status = project_status) }

proj_activity_grouped <- function(query_id, ...) {
    grouping_vars <- quos(...)

    proj_activity_report(query_id) %>% 
        group_by(!!!grouping_vars)
}

proj_activity_summ <- function(query_id, grouping_vars, summ_var) {
    query_id <- enquo(query_id)
    summ_var <- enquo(summ_var)
    grouping_vars <- quos(grouping_vars)

    proj_activity_grouped(query_id, !!!grouping_vars) %>% 
        summarise(total = sum(!!summ_var))
}
```

The function `proj_activity_report()` works fine, and `proj_activity_grouped()` seems to work fine, as I've tested it by calling

```
proj_activity_grouped(102, Worker_Name) %>% 
  summarise(total_duration = sum(Duration_mins))
```

which gives the output I would expect:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
       Worker_Name total_duration
             <chr>          <dbl>
 1      Ahmed Khan            690
 2   Craig Stanton           1245
 3   Darnell Lewis           1395
 4 David Silverman            960
 5  Frankie Benton           1275
 6     Jane Benton            855
 7          Li Fan           1275
 8     Maria Gomes           1200
 9    Sunil Khanna           1080
10  Suzanne Watson           1380
11  Theresa Briers           1395
12   Valerie Jones           1500
```

(This is dummy data, all of the names are fake.)

It's `proj_activity_summ()` where things fall down. With the code above I get an error `Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 'match' requires vector arguments`. I expect it's to do with the way I'm handling the variables, but I cannot figure out which bit is wrong.

NB. I'm using `dplyr` version 0.7.0.

Comment: I can only make a guess but it looks like your error is actually with `filter` in `proj_activity_report()`, which is looking for `vector` arguments. The only argument that is passed from `proj_activity_summ()` to `proj_activity_report()` **and** which `filter` uses is `query_id`. It looks like the way you're handling `query_id` in `proj_activity_summ()` is somehow wrong. Quote/unquote `query_id` in different ways in `proj_activity_summ()`?

Comment: I don't think you need to use `enquo` with `query_id` in the last function.  The real problem I had is with your grouping variables list.  It only worked for me if in the last function you again used `quos` on  `...` instead of `grouping_variables`.